# Problems when drawing bounding boxes manually

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to draw bounding boxes manually using openCV. The bounding boxes coordinates is gathered using tensorflow object detection API.

When I get the coordinates, they are normalized, so I convert them and then add them to the image like so:

```
boxes = np.squeeze(detections['detection_boxes'])
scores = np.squeeze(detections['detection_scores'])
min_score_thresh = 0.7
bboxes = boxes[scores > min_score_thresh]

im_width, im_height,_ = image.shape
for box in bboxes:
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = int(xmin * im_width), int(xmax * im_width), int(ymin * im_height), int(ymax * im_height)
    cv2.rectangle(image_np_with_detections, (xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),(0,0,255),5)
    cv2.putText(image_np_with_detections,"TEST",(int(xmin),int(ymin)-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,1,(0,0,255), 1)
```

Then I compare this rectangle with the ones that Tensorflow API generates like so:

```
viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np_with_detections,
    detections['detection_boxes'],
    detections['detection_classes'] + label_id_offset,
    detections['detection_scores'],
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    max_boxes_to_draw=5,
    min_score_thresh=.7,
    agnostic_mode=False)

#Show the image
cv2.imshow('object detection', image_np_with_detections)
```

But as the image below shows the bounding box that is drawn manualy is off. What could be the cause to this?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

EDIT:
After swapping `im_width,im_height` to `im_height,im_width` I now get:

[image]

Comment: try switching `im_width, im_height,_ = image.shape` to `height, width, _ = ...`

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks for your reply! I seems that it helped a lot. But for a reason it draws it bigger than it should be (new image has been attached in the post).

Comment: In `ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = int(xmin * im_width), int(xmax * im_width), int(ymin * im_height), int(ymax * im_height)` the left and right side don't match. e.g. you have the equivalent of `ymin = int(xmin * im_width)`.

Comment: @DanMašek Of course! How could I not see that?! Works perfectly now, the bounding boxes are spot on each other. Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

The logic error lies on this line:

```
im_width, im_height, _ = image.shape
```

As opencv image arrays are structured in this manner: `(height, width, channels)`, you would need to swap the positions you put the `im_width` and `im_height` in:

```
im_height, im_width, _ = image.shape
```

Also, this line:

```
ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = int(xmin * im_width), int(xmax * im_width), int(ymin * im_height), int(ymax * im_height)
```

as you can see, should be:

```
ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = int(ymin * im_height), int(xmin * im_width), int(ymax * im_height), int(xmax * im_width)
```